# Merge stops working after package 'config' is loaded

Tags: r, merge, config

I'm getting a most peculiar error. My programs which works perfectly, throws an error after I load the 'config' library

```
out<-merge(x=out1,y=out2, by="Group.1",all=F)

 Error in merge(x = out1, y = out2, by = "Group.1", all = F) : 
 unused arguments (x = out1, y = out2, by = "Group.1", all = F)
```

But if I comment out the `library("config")` line, the code resumes working.

Comment: check that there isn't a `config::merge` function. If so, replace `merge` with `base::merge`.

Comment: Yep, that solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As dash2 mentioned in the comments, the issue was happening because config library also had a merge function and can be solved by replacing

```
merge
```

with

```
base::merge
```